# Need help identifying this transformer in a tire balancer

Tags: transformer, identification

I have a tire balancer circuit board I'm trying to fix and am having trouble figuring out if I can get one of these (pic included). I believe it's a transformer but I'm not sure its ratings and such. I know I need a new capacitor also but I found those available online for 50 cents. The numbers on top read 71142 A and the side reads HI-POT OK.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It’s a common-mode choke (noise filter, not a transformer per se.)

That said, it might make more sense to replace the entire power supply than to attempt to repair it yourself. That unit was subjected to a severe stress - overvoltage surge probably - and likely has other damage that you’ve yet to find.

Power supplies are cheap; your personal safety is not.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a transformer. It is a common mode suppression choke.

Comment: thank you! I would have never known that. Do you know where I may be able to purchase one?

Comment: From any shop that sells electronic components, maybe? What shops did you search and not found any?